# [React]Jest SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've been really struggling and i cannot figure out how to make this work.
There seems to be tons of questions on this subject and i tried every one of them and i still seem to be having a problem running jest. import just does not seem to work at all.
So please can anyone assist me in solving this problem.

Error

```js
C:\Users\admin\Documents\my-app\_tests_\main.spec.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

main.spec.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Home } from '../src/Home';

test('Basic Test', () => {
  expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
});
```

Running this will create the error, but if i comment out the import line it works.

bablerc

```js
{
    "plugins": [
            "transform-async-functions",
            "transform-object-rest-spread",
            "transform-regenerator"
          ],
     "presets": [
            "es2015",
            "react"
          ]
}
```

I've tried to add the "env": {"test": {"plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]}} but it didn't do anything so i took it out for now.

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "webpack -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV=\"'production'\" --define process.env.SERVER_ROOT=\"'${SERVER_ROOT}'\"",
    "start-dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.1",
    "npm": "3.10.8"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
       "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": { "\\.(s?css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy" }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^3.3.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.46.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.13.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sails.io.js": "^1.1.10",
    "socket.io-client": "1.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Things change quickly in the js world. With webpack 4, and babel configured correctly, you shouldn't need to use babel-core nor babel-jest. Just use presets `env`, `react`, `stage-0` to babelrc. If using `modules: false` on root level, you'll need to use `modules: true` on the test environment. Unexpected token import usually means babel is not converting to commonJs modules for jest/node to consume.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell jest to import your files using Babel.
It can be done by setting the `transform` attribute of `jest` in your `package.json` :

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes thank you! that made the imports but now i'm getting an error for SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when i tried to import my own script with import { Home} from '../src/Home';

Comment: ({"Object<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){:global .react-datepicker__tether-element-attached-top .react-datepicker__triangle, :global .react-datepicker__tether-element-attached-bottom .react-datepicker__triangle, :global .react-datepicker__year-read-view--down-arrow, :global .react-datepicker__month-read-view--down-arrow

Comment: Seems like it's having a problem with react.datepicker

Comment: Sounds like you are importing your style. You can add this part on your `package.json`, in the jest part :

"moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(s?css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
 }

Comment: I've added that portion to my package.json but the error still there.

Comment: I think the error you are getting now is independent from the initial one this post is about. Can you show the piece of code that create the error ?

Comment: Yeah, i updated the code in the question. the problem is when i tried to import my home.js. if i comment that out it works